# Proper way to clean git history on master

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-revert

I am on branch "master".
I had such git history:

```
333  (#82)
444  (#83)
```

Then I done some commits and reverts (222->111->010->789->456->123):

```
123 Revert "(#84)"
456 Revert "(#81)"
789 Revert “(#81)"
010 Revert "(#86)"
111  (#86)
222  (#84)
333  (#82)
444  (#83)
```

I need somehow to clear those wrong steps (222->111->010->789->456->123) to return history back to :

```
333  (#82)
444  (#83)
```

will it be ok if i do:

```
git rebase -i 333
```

and will drop wrong commits?
then

```
git push -f
```

Comment: did you push the commits and reverts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you haven't pushed the commits and reverts,* do the following:

```
git reflog
```

This will give you a list of ops (incl. all reverts and commits) in reverse chronological order. Find the last stable commit and find its head in the form of `HEAD@{somenumber}`. Then to fall back to that commit, do the following:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{somenumber}
```

Comment: I think he already knows the hash, which is `333`, so the command would be `git reset --hard 333`